# Oracle Compound Trigger : PLS-00103 Encountered when Attempting to get Max of Date Column

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, database-trigger

I am trying to construct a trigger that will update Table B with Max value end_date column when the corresponding end_date of table A is updated.

This is so I can calculated and save the date difference between a date that I have saved prior to this, and the max end date that I want constantly updated from Table A.

So far compound trigger seems like a valid solution given that my row trigger does not fully cover all the use cases, however, I got the error stated in the title.

Full error:

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ")" when expecting one of the following:      current delete exists prior

I have tried to find out any syntax error that I might have overlooked, but so far I can't manage to progress.

The database version seemed to be correct as well, as I am using oracle 11g which should support compound triggers.

This is the aforementioned SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER DATE_DIFF_CALC_A
FOR UPDATE OR INSERT OF END_ON ON TABLE_A
COMPOUND TRIGGER
   TYPE temp_record IS RECORD (
      COUNTER           NUMBER,
      B_ID             TABLE_B.id%TYPE,
      U_ID             TABLE_B.U_ID%TYPE,
      U_TYPE           TABLE_B.U_TYPE%TYPE,
      U_VOL_NO         TABLE_B.U_VOL_NO%TYPE,
      MAX_DATE         TABLE_B.MAX_DATE%TYPE,
   ); 

   TYPE temp_table IS TABLE OF temp_record INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER; 

   row_record temp_table;

   AFTER EACH ROW IS
     COUNTER NUMBER;
     MAX_DATE DATE;
     B_ID NUMBER;
   BEGIN
      SELECT COUNT(*), MAX_DATE, ID
      INTO COUNTER,
           MAX_DATE,
           B_ID
      FROM TABLE_B
      WHERE U_ID = :NEW.U_ID
        AND U_TYPE = :NEW.TYPE AND U_VOL_NO = :NEW.U_VOL_NO GROUP BY ID, MAX_DATE;
-- Tool I am using for query tells me there is an error in this line, but there's nothing here :(
      row_record(row_record.COUNT + 1).COUNTER := COUNTER;
      row_record(row_record.COUNT).MAX_DATE := MAX_DATE;
      row_record(row_record.COUNT).B_ID := B_ID;
      row_record(row_record.COUNT).U_ID := :NEW.U_ID;
      row_record(row_record.COUNT).U_TYPE := :NEW.TYPE;
      row_record(row_record.COUNT).U_VOL_NO := :NEW.U_VOL_NO;
   END AFTER EACH ROW; 

   AFTER STATEMENT IS 
      new_max_enddate   TABLE_B.MAX_DATE%TYPE;
   BEGIN
      FOR indx IN 1 .. row_record.COUNT
      LOOP
         SELECT MAX(a.end_on)
          INTO new_max_enddate
          from TABLE_A a, TABLE_C C 
          where a.c_id = c.id and UPPER(c.place_name) not like 'XTEST%'
          and a.status not in ('1', '2', '3', '4')
          and a.U_ID = row_record(indx).U_ID
          and a.TYPE = row_record(indx).U_TYPE
          and a.U_VOL_NO = row_record(indx).U_VOL_NO;

        IF row_record(indx).COUNTER = 1 THEN
           IF new_max_enddate > row_record(indx).MAX_DATE THEN 
              UPDATE TABLE_B 
                 SET MAX_DATE = new_max_enddate 
                WHERE U_ID = :NEW.U_ID
                AND U_TYPE = :NEW.TYPE
                AND U_VOL_NO = :NEW.U_VOL_NO;
           END IF;
        END IF;
      END LOOP; 
   END AFTER STATEMENT; 
END DATE_DIFF_CALC_A;
```

I commented on the line of code that the tool I am using tells me the error is at, if it helps at all.

Do forgive me if this problem is suppose to be easy to solve; I am still not that familiar with PL/SQL and would love to learn more.

Comment: Couple of syntax errors noticeable : `FOR UPDATE OR INSERT OF END_ON ON TABLE_A`  should be `FOR UPDATE  OF END_ON OR INSERT ON`. Remove the  comma after `TABLE_B.MAX_DATE%TYPE`

Comment: The comma helped me progress. Thanks !

Comment: @KaushikNayak Your suggestion works! The comma was the one causing the issue. The `FOR UPDATE OR INSERT OF END_ON ON TABLE_A` statement works as expected and was not considered a syntax error in my case. Although my code also suffers from multiple other syntax error other that the one you suggested, your suggestion is ultimately the one that helped me progress. Mind if you submit it in the form of an answer so I may accept it? Thanks!

Comment: Alphonsus : Done.....!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove the comma after `TABLE_B.MAX_DATE%TYPE`

Also,

`FOR UPDATE OR INSERT OF END_ON ON TABLE_A` should be `FOR UPDATE OF END_ON OR INSERT ON`

Answer (score 1):

Your temp_table definition defines a [collection](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005) known as a nested table. You cannot access an entry beyond the count attribute for the collection. While the number of entries is 'unlimited' you increase the number of entries by EXTENDing the collection. So in this case, after the comment for the error you need.

```
row_record.extend;
row_record(row_record.count).counter  := counter;
row_record(row_record.count).max_date := max_date;
...
```

Comment: This does help me a little, but I still face issues from other parts.@Kaushik Nayak comment also helped me to progress. I will update after I get it solved. Thanks